# how to submit a form with rvest when the submit button is part of another element, than the one that have the inputs to be filled

Tags: r, forms, submit, rvest

I meet some difficulties to submit a form with different elements. let's try with the following example:

```
session <- html_session("https://www.change.org/p/ne-touchez-pas-a-la-loi-littoral-loilittoral")
form <- html_form(session)
```

the values to be filled are within the element 3

```
form[[3]]<-set_values(form[[3]], 'first_name' = "kevin", 'last_name' = "smith", 'email' = "kevin.smith@hotmail.com", 'country_code' = "64", 'postal_code' = "75015")
session$url <-"https://www.change.org/p/ne-touchez-pas-a-la-loi-littoral-loilittoral"
```

but the submit button is within the element 2. So if i submit the form[[2]], the values of the form[[3]] will not be filled

```
 session <- submit_form(session, form[[2]])
```

by the way i get the following error:

```
Submitting with 'abuse_sub_category'
Error in xml2::url_absolute(form$url, session$url) : 
not compatible with STRSXP
```

i met another problem, the value filled for the country is not taken into account

```
> form[[3]]
<form> '<unnamed>' (POST )
<input hidden> 'petition_id': 10053332
<input hidden> 'alert_id': 
<input text> 'first_name': kevin
<input text> 'last_name': smith
<input email> 'email': kevin.smith@hotmail.com
<select> 'country_code' [1/259]
<input text> 'postal_code': 75015
```